# Post request method on server calling twice. Why so?

Tags: node.js, express

1st Time, it is doing the expected thing. 
But I don't know why it is calling itself again and even though I have undefined checks all over, it is still printing.

```
router.post('/:id?', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    if (id!== 'undefined') {
        debugger;
    console.log(req.method);  
    console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
        console.log(req.body.query.toString());
    }

    if(req.body != 'undefined')
        res.render('index', { title: 'Shisodia Mimanshu', query: 'Random Query', text: 'Success 111' + req.body.query });
});
```

**Output at console:**

```
1

POST
body: {"query":"hahahhahahha"}

hahahhahahha

POST /1 200 55.494 ms - 1015

undefined

POST

body: {}

POST / 500 13.445 ms - 1408
```

Comment: And req.body.query.toString() throwing exception 2nd time. I mean if something is undefined,  it is still getting inside and even if it is getting inside, why it is throwing error. Strange behavior. I'd rather say it is a bug.

Comment: What is the URL you are sending it? Define "calling it twice". What is the `console.log` output you are seeing?

Comment: 1
POST
body: {"query":"hahahhahahha"}
hahahhahahha
POST /1 200 55.494 ms - 1015
undefined
POST
body: {}
POST / 500 13.445 ms - 1408

this is the output of console

Comment: And how are you making the URL call? What client are you using?

Comment: Using Jquery Ajax call.

Comment: Post your code. Your logs indicate there actually are 2 requests coming in.

Comment: $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
      var data = {};
      data.query = $('#txtQuery').val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000',
        success: function(data) {
        }
      });
      });

This is the Post request

Comment: make sure you bind the click event only once.. some more code would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The response for this post method is not sent that is the reason you are getting two outputs.The server call ends once the response is sent back to the client. And checking the Id for null should be changes from 'undefined', 'undefined' is a string.

```
router.post('/:id?', function (req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;
console.log(id);
if (id!= null) {
    debugger;
console.log(req.method);  
console.log('body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    console.log(req.body.query.toString());
res.end('Completed')
}

if(req.body != null)
    res.render('index', { title: 'Shisodia Mimanshu', query: 'Random Query', text: 'Success     111' + req.body.query });
res.end('Done')
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this may be it. I still don't understand why it would go twice, though!

Comment: res.end('Done') is not a solution. Because I want to render the page and if I write this, it will only render Done message.

Comment: you can use res.end() instead of res.end('Done').